# using click function with ngb-accordion

Tags: html, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

[accordion image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eB4hY.jpg)
I am new to angular. I want use a click function inside accordion so that when the panel title is clicked, the student name mapped to it is passed to my function in the component. can anybody help me out.

I tried putting click with ngb-panel as well as ng-template, but both failed. Also i tried to wrap the template inside a span and linking click function to it, but it also didn't worked out. I am able to get the panel ID in my component but i need the data object also.

```
Info Array

    [{
    "firstName": "Sagar",
    "middleName": "Alias",
    "lastName": "jacky",
    "statusCode": {
            "ResultCode": "ERR",
            "Messages": [{
                    "code": "E0501",
                    "text": "tripNameAM is not present in our records",
                    "data": "tripNameAM"
                },
                {
                    "code": "E05012",
                    "text": "tripNamePM is not present in our records"
                    "data": "tripNamePM"
                }
                           ]
        }
    }
]



<div id="collapseExample" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed" class="accordion">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" activeIds="ngb-panel-0" (panelChange)="test($event)">
                    <ngb-panel *ngFor="let data of info" title="{{data.firstName+' '+data.middleName+' '+data.lastName}}">
                        <ng-template ngbPanelContent *ngFor="let message of data.statusCode.Messages">
                                {{message.text}}
                        </ng-template>
                    </ngb-panel>
                </ngb-accordion>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

below is what i tried,

```
<div id="collapseExample" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed" class="accordion">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" activeIds="ngb-panel-0" (panelChange)="test($event)">
                    <ngb-panel *ngFor="let data of info" title="{{data.firstName+' '+data.middleName+' '+data.lastName}}" (click)="getStudentname(data)">
                        <ng-template ngbPanelContent *ngFor="let message of data.statusCode.Messages">
                                {{message.text}}
                        </ng-template>
                    </ngb-panel>
                </ngb-accordion>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

component

```
//imports..

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css', './mdb.scss']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {

constructor(private http: Http){}
...
...
getStudentname(data){

console.log(data);

}

}
```

i want to get the student name mapped to a panel when it's title is clicked. Can anybody point me to the right direction.

Comment: Can you add how you tried to implement the click event on the `ngb-panel`?

Comment: i have added the details, please check.

Comment: Can you also include your component?

Comment: details added. Please check

Comment: But where is your `info` array? You iterate that in your template

Comment: added info array.

Comment: Is the title of the panel displayed correctly?

Comment: yes. title is correctly displayed. please check the image link.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/examples#header), you can customise the header also. Wrap the header inside an element, and place `click` element on it. Also, you create several `ng-template` element, which is probably not what you want to do, also put that into a container element:

```
<ngb-panel *ngFor="let data of info" title="{{data.firstName+' '+data.middleName+' '+data.lastName}}" (click)="getStudentname(data)">
  <ng-template ngbPanelContent >
    <span *ngFor="let message of data.statusCode.Messages">
       {{message.text}}
    </span>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template ngbPanelHeader>
    <div (click)="getStudentName(data)">
      {{data.firstName+' '+data.middleName+' '+data.lastName}}
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</ngb-panel>
```